# Are we able to properly use the `main` element yet?

Tags: html

So I just remembered that people were going on about the `main` element and whether or not it's a good idea and whether or not we should use it or even have one to begin with. I also remember being against the idea of a `main` element.

But as I was typing `<div id="main"`, I asked myself, "If I'm applying `main` to an `id`, then why not see if the `main` element has been standardized yet?"

---

So then I looked it up. [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/) says yes we can use it. But from their article, it looks like it's still not fully supported. I know that we can use JavaScript to make things easier for late-comers (browsers not adopting the new Standards as quickly as others) - and I know that [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic) (.com) says the major browsers support it, but has anyone had any issues while using it?

Are there any reasons I'm not aware of why I shouldn't use it?

Comment: I didn’t vote to close, but this is rather opinion-based. There are good descriptions on the situation, and it’s largely a matter of opinions how you weigh things. And there is really no tangible benefit from using `main`; it’s an authoring style issue more than anything else.

Comment: Ok, as per others' advice, I can safely use the `main` element, but in the current release of IE, it does not work as expected without JavaScript so I'll have to wait until there is full support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not trying to be a smart ass but to elaborate on Stephen Thomas' answer:

If you need to support IE8 or older you might want to add the latest version of the [HTML5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) (if you haven't already) or add this to the `head` of your page above your `stylesheet`(s):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script>
        (function (d) {
            d.createElement('MAIN');
            // ... more HTML5 elements
        }(document));
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

And the CSS (as Stephen Thomas already described):

```
main {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is broad support for `<main>` but if you have to deal with older browsers, the following CSS rule will make it work for them

```
main {
    display: block;
}
```

The CSS specification requires browsers to treat all elements they don't recognize as `inline`, so this rule tells them to treat it properly as `block` instead.

If you need to support a browser so old that it doesn't implement CSS, that's another ballgame.